# Why is text placed differently in <input>s than <span>s or <textarea>s?

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to build a jQuery plugin that fakes the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute (like [What is the most accurate way to emulate the "placeholder" attribute in browsers that don't support it natively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575621/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-emulate-the-placeholder-attribute-in-browsers)). To do this I’m inserting a `<span>` before the appropriate `<input>` or `<textarea>` and duplicating the styling.

Unfortunately, I’ve discovered that browsers magically place the text differently in `<input>`s than `<span>`s or `<textarea>`s, as demonstrated by http://jsfiddle.net/63zcD/1/—the text is vertically centered in the `<input>`, even though Web Inspector says the styling is identical across all three. The effect appears in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

Tricks that haven’t worked:

- `vertical-align: middle;`, `vertical-align: text-bottom;`
- `display: inline-block;`

Twitter’s login page fakes the `placeholder` attribute, but they get around this problem by wrapping the `<span>` and `<input>`/`<textarea>` in a containing `<div>` and manually styling the `<span>` for a visual match, which isn’t an option for a plugin that needs to run automatically.

Comment: It's based on how the OS aligns its text in various controls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assigning a line-height that is equal to the element height should work.  See this fork of your original fiddle, so to speak: http://jsfiddle.net/pygPs/.

A quick browser check showed it rendering properly in IE 9, IE 6, as well as the latest Mac versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.  I didn't change any of the existing CSS from the original link, just added one line:

```
height: 26px;
line-height: 26px; /*added this line*/
```

Comment: No prob.  I never get the vertical-align property to work.  I figured out that I have better success with it on block elements (as opposed to inline elements like spans), but I still don't love it.  I just bumped into this page that's a nice little summary of its problems (and it suggests the line-height property as well): http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html